# How to install xapk, apks, or multiple-apks via adb?

Tags: adb, apk

`xapk`, `apks`, or `multiple-apks` is the new standard for apps that is basically one folder and multiple apks in it.

I know there are apps like apkpure or SAI that can do it, but I want to know how to it manually.

I know we can use `adb install-multiple` to install signed apks but if they are unsigned how can I do it if I have the root?

I used to be able to copy and paste single apk to `/system/priv-app/${folder}` to bypass the signature check but simply copying and pasting multiple apks under the same folder doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: AFAIK XAPK is no official format by Google, it is more a community driven package format. The official format is "Android App Bundle" (aab) which is installed using the tool [bundletool](https://github.com/google/bundletool) (by Google).

Comment: @Robert ok, so if i have multiple apks, is it possible to put them in `/system/priv-app/${folder}` and get it to work, if not, how can I make an aab a system app?

Comment: What do you mean by `but if they are unsigned how can I do it if I have the root`? APK files always have to be signed if you want to install them.

Answer (score 21):

For those who are trying to install XAPK files through `adb` because their XAPK Installer does not work on their Android phone, I've got you covered.

[You must have Android Debug Bridge (ADB) set up and working.](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)

XAPK files are basically [ZIP Archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)) files (described by their PK header at the beginning of the file)
This means we are able to open/extract those files using any ZIP tool that we have (I prefer [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/))

Once we have extracted the files from the archive, we are only interested in .APK files.
Open the Command Prompt/Terminal in the folder where you've extracted the archive,

and type the following command: `adb install-multiple "AppName.apk" "ConfigA.apk" "ConfigB.apk"`

#### Notes

- The order of files in the command does not matter.
- AppName, ConfigA and ConfigB are examples, they will differ depending on the package.
- There might be more APK files, make sure to include them all.
- If there are several APK files with different architectures, make sure to check your phones CPU architecture before proceeding with installing the APK.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a guide on how to install an XAPK file to your Android device via adb on a Windows machine:

1. Rename your `.xapk` file to `.zip`.
2. Unzip the file to a new folder.
3. In the new folder, you will see a few `.apk` files, and sometimes also a folder `Android` which includes a `.obb` file (you can ignore the following files: `icon.png` and `manifast.json`).
4. Open a [Command Prompt](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-command-prompt-2618089) from within the new folder and run `adb install-multiple "com.application.name.apk" "config.one.apk" "config.xxhdpi.apk"` (these apk names are just an example; replace them with the apk names you see in your folder).
5. if your XAPK file contains a `.obb` file (you should see a folder named `Android`), then run also the following: `adb push Android\obb\com.application.name /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/` (replace `com.application.name` with the name of the apk you are installing).
6. Done!

I also include a few notes from [@user337422](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232725/327095)'s excellent answer:

- There might be more APK files, make sure to include them all.
- If there are several APK files with different architectures (example: `config.arm64_v8a.apk`), make sure to check your phone's CPU architecture before proceeding with installing the APK.