# How to prepare full APK ready for side loading?

Tags: apk, side-loading

I've just bought HiSense A5 Pro CC (no Google Play) so I have to side load apps. Maybe it is only a coincidence but so far I have mixed results with creating APK files from my other phone (Samsung XCover 3 or A52s using for example APK Extractor or CX File Manager). Some apps runs fine, some do not respond at all. I.e. after installing them, and then trying to launch the icon only flickers and that's it.

On the other hand all apps I found on APK Mirror website runs fine. I noticed also that the apps I extracted by myself are smaller in size than the ones APK Mirror provides. So my guess is the packages created manually by me are missing some resources.

So how to create truly full APK in APK Mirror fashion?

*I am asking since APK Mirror does not cover all useful apps after all. OSM Tracker for example runs fine after "manual" extraction, but I had no such lack with Open Weather -- I extracted it and side loaded with no effect, launching causes icon to blink and that's it.*

Comment: Are you aware that apps installed from Google PlayStore nowadays consist of multiple APK files (aka "app bundle" or "split APKs") see https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228374/2241 and https://android.stackexchange.com/q/245550/2241

Comment: As @Robert indicates, it might have to do with the way how you "manually created" those packages. As you sisn't specify, maybe take a look at [this script](https://codeberg.org/izzy/Adebar/src/branch/master/tools/getapk) (part of a project of mine) to see what pieces you might be missing – or feel free to use it directly.

Comment: @Izzy, By "manually created by me" I meant what I wrote in the post -- extracting APK from other phone using APK Extractor or CX File Manager. There are no settings for this operation so there is not much to write about, you click on app, and the APK is extracted.

Comment: @Robert Ah, I see (I think) your point. I should create "APKs" file, not "APK", correct? I just tested SuperBackup (on source phone) and installed it with APK Mirror app, and this combo worked. So far tested OpenWeather but it is promising.

Comment: @greenoldman then maybe those apps do not support split APKs. APK Extractor for example wasn't updated for almost 3 years now. I don't know which ones do support this (my script does), but you could take a look at e.g. [APK Kit](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.github.ghmxr.apkextractor) or [Kanade](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/io.alexrintt.kanade). No promises, though.

Comment: It seems to me that it is really a programming question and off-topic here.

Comment: @RohitGupta, where do you see programming? Using apps like Skype, Backup or OsmAnd  is programming according to you?