# Adb backups save no data

Tags: adb, backup, android-12, oneplus

I want to reinstall the OS on my `OnePlus` phone running `Android 12`. Before I do that I would like to backup some of my apps which don't store their data in the cloud. The phone is `not rooted`, so I have tried using `Helium` which is apparently dead, but I still tried it. While trying to enable it I found that my phone wasn't recognized by adb as a device, but this was fixed by [adding the backup password](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116439/adb-backup-command-on-non-rooted-device-creates-an-empty-backup-file), but the app just crashes when trying to backup briefly displaying this:
[image: Helium error message]

As you can see it also clicks on the "set password" option which just opens desktop. The funny thing is: I don't think I can disable the password now, so...

So after this didn't work I tried looking into backing up with `ADB` in `PowerShell` on my `Windows 11` pc, but It seems to have issues with doing backups.

To list the files I just do: `adb shell pm list packages -f -3`

Let's say that out of those I would like to backup this one:
`package:/data/app/~~yCw1hZQNzK2LConsvhuejg==/com.rovio.BadPiggiesHD-pMe0TFd1aaE5-WduzwZ1Zw==/base.apk=com.rovio.BadPiggiesHD`

It pulls the `.apk` file no problem with this command:

`adb pull "/data/app/~~yCw1hZQNzK2LConsvhuejg==/com.rovio.BadPiggiesHD-pMe0TFd1aaE5-WduzwZ1Zw==/base.apk" ".\BP.apk"`

Although, a little suspicious that it is only 58MB when it should be more like 170.

But trying to make a backup with this line:

`adb backup "/data/app/~~yCw1hZQNzK2LConsvhuejg==/com.rovio.BadPiggiesHD-pMe0TFd1aaE5-WduzwZ1Zw==/base.apk=com.rovio.BadPiggiesHD"`

generates an empty `backup.ab` file (literally 0B) even if I pass just `com.rovio.BadPiggiesHD` as an argument.

I have also tried using the advice from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482042/adb-backup-does-not-work) and adding quotes around the arguments, so ideally it I want something like this since I need both an apk and data:

`adb backup "-apk com.rovio.BadPiggiesHD -f C:\Users\name\Desktop\app_backups\`

But this just spits out `Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation.` and stops instantly without doing anything.

I have even tried:

`adb backup "-apk -shared -all -f C:\Users\name\Desktop\app_backups\full_backup.ab"`

I don't need all apps, but this generates an empty file too.

What is the cause of this issue? I am at a loss since there are no error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets get through your questions:

#### Using adb backup on Android 12+ devices

`adb backup` is mostly useless on Android devices running Android 12+, it will only work for apps that have been developed and released before Android 12.

> For apps that target Android 12 (API level 31) or higher, when a user runs the adb backup command, app data is excluded from any other system data that is exported from the device.

For more details see my answer to [Does adb backup/restore still work because it says it's deprecated?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/231237/2241)

#### Pulled APK file via adb is a bit small

> Although, a little suspicious that it is only 58MB when it should be more like 170.
> `adb pull "/data/app/~~yCw1hZQNzK2LConsvhuejg==/com.rovio.BadPiggiesHD-pMe0TFd1aaE5-WduzwZ1Zw==/base.apk" ".\BP.apk"`

On recent Android devices apps are not downloaded from Google Play Store as single APK file but as bunch of split APKs. You can see that in `adb shell pm path com.example.someapp` as it will output multiple APK files for one app. YAouu need all of them, otherwise the app will not work.

For details how to extract split APK files from a device see the question [How to get a split apk from a device via adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228374/2241)

#### `adb backup adb backup /data/app/<somepath>/base.apk` does not work

The command `adb backup` does accept as arguments only app package names, never a path to a file on the device. Therefore this command will never work.

#### Backup everything (data+apps) via adb creates empty file

If you execute a command like `adb backup "-apk -shared -all -f backup.ab` and it does create an empty file, it could be that the backup binary `bu` is bugged or missing on your device.

If you execute a command like `adb backup <arguments>`, an adb connection will be established and on the device the command `bu <arguments>` will be executed. I have seen devices where the `bu` command was simply defect. You can test this by opening `adb shell` yourself and then try to execute `bu --help`.  If this prints an error message or may be even `/system/bin/sh: bu: inaccessible or not found` then adb backup can not work on your device.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. It seems like `bu` is fine since It outputs the manual as it should no problem. And the app in question was released in 2012, so I doubt it was made for android 12+ :). Also, are you saying that there is basically no way to backup data on 12+ and if you need to switch to another phone or reset the current one you just lose all of your in-app data? There must be another way, right?

Comment: @user9102437 Even if the app is old it can simply deny backup in it's manifest, then adb backup will also create an empty backup. If you need to switch to a new phone you can use direct USB-to-USB connection. This is the way Google want you to transfer data to a new device.

Comment: Fair enough, but what If it is the same phone like in my case? Do I actually need a separate 256GB phone to not lose my stuff? This is ridiculous. No amount of security is worth this stupidity.

Comment: @user9102437 From Google perspective of course they prefer GDrive cloud backup. To my experience most apps deny backup (`allowBackup=false` in AndroidManifest.xml) so no matter which backup or migration technique you try you will loose most app data when reinstalling the phone or moving to a new one.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I hate the idea of using GDrive because I don't think this will work on the apps which are not from the play store (which I have a quite a few of). And, this also means that I still need to backup APKs because god knows which version of the 3rd party app did I install. This honestly feels like the kind of thing Apple would do, but they at least give you iTunes for backup which DOES save app data. I guess I will be looking at other ways. Maybe will update something here if I succeed

Comment: As an experiment I have decompiled the `base.apk` for `com.rovio.BadPiggiesHD` and actually in `AndroidManifest.xml` it clearly states ` <application android:allowBackup="true"` but the file size is still 0... Could it be an issue with PowerShell maybe? I have redownloaded the sdk from the official site and tried using cmd too to no avail.

Comment: Holy shit, I think I figured it out. I used `adb logcat > log.txt` to find what was going on and found this: `BackupManagerService: Backup password mismatch; aborting`. So this whole time my phone was asking for a password and I just didn't see it. I was just pressing "Allow backup" and since now I have set the password, leaving the field blank no longer works... Now the file is full of data) Hopefully, it will be able to restore from this. I will check this.