# How do I install split apk in Bluestacks 5?

Tags: bluestacks

I shared my Minecraft (Android) installation files using ShareIt to my PC. It sent 4 split apks and 1 base apk. How do I make it install in my Bluestacks 5?

Comment: Have you tried [How to install xapk, apks, or multiple-apks via adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221204/2241) ?