How to pack an xapk into an apk?
is there a way to have an apk (also splitted for different architectures) from an xapk file?
I'm looking online but I can't find anything useful. I would like to have the apks splitted per abi.

An xapk is just a ZIP files of multiple split APK files. Therefore just extract it.

@Robert if I try to install the extracted apk after I rename the xapk in zip, adb can't install the apk because it says "missing split files". I would like to have one big apk with all the xapk files

Have you read the posts about installing an xapk like this one? https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221204/2241 If yes, please name the app you are trying the xapk of.

While the question itself is valid, albeit a multi-part (1. how to extract XAPK into split APK, and 2. how to build a fat APK using split APK), there's a possibility that this question falls into an XY-problem where the real question is to install split APKs. Consider clarify the real issue.

@Robert, yes, I've read the thread and I can't find my solution. I know how to install xapk using adb, I would like to know if there's a way to make the xapk an apk file. Just one file instead of having a zip file full of apks.

@AndrewT. The real issue is I want to have one (big) apk file instead of multiple apks inside a zip folder (xapk)

@AndrewT. In the duplicate I can't find the SAP app, do you have any link? Furthermore the blog post is unavailable

Note that if you create one big APK from multiple split APK files the APK signature will be invalid, thus you have to re-sign the APK. If the app checks the signature it will refuse to run

@Robert, yes, I know, thank you (I discovered this after 2 hours of debugging...). Now, when I make some modifications to the code, I have to resign every apk
